# ¿Cómo mostrar la relación OneToOne en los formularios correspondientes a ambas clases relacionadas?

Tags: django-3.2.4

Tengo dos clases que se relacionan entre sí a través de un `OneToOneField`, pero la administración de Django sólo muestra el campo en el formulario correspondiente a la clase en donde está definido y quisiera que saliera en los respectivos formularios de ambas clases sin tener que utilizar fieldset. Buscando en internet, encontré una forma que supuestamente debería resolver mi problema, quedando de esta forma:

**En models.py:**

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    cuenta = models.OneToOneField('CuentaBancaria', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('cuenta bancaria'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cliente_cuenta')
    ....


class CuentaBancaria(models.Model):
    ....
```

**En admin.py:**

```
class CuentaBancariaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'cliente_cuenta']
    fields = [....,'cliente_cuenta']
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> FieldError at /admin/app_name/cuentabancaria/add/ Unknown field(s)
> (cliente_cuenta) specified for CuentaBancaria. Check
> fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CuentaBancariaAdmin.

¿Cómo puedo mostrar esta relación en los formularios correspondientes a las clases relacionadas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este código pude resolver mi problema, aunque tuve que hacer cambios en otros archivos y modifiqué algunos métodos del formulario; pero el cambio fundamental fue este:

**En admin.py:**

```
class CuentaBancariaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cliente = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cliente.objects.all(), label="Cliente")
    
    class Meta:
        model = CuentaBancaria
        fields=('cliente', ....)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance=self.instance
        if instance.pk:
            if Cliente.objects.filter(cuenta=instance).exists():
                self.initial['cliente'] = Cliente.objects.get(cuenta=instance)
                ....

class CuentaBancariaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'cliente_cuenta']
    form=CuentaBancariaForm
```